# unable to add ripple effect on the drawable that is being drawn on the view dynamically

Tags: android, drawable, ondraw, ripple

I have prepapred a CustomView with x height and y width (by extending View). This view has a background. and in this view, I am drawing a drawable. User can move that drawable within its x and y limit. Now  want to add ripple effect on that drawable for pressed and focused state. Actually I am also unable to focus on that drawable when this view is focused.

```
    public class CustomView extends View {
    Drawable image; 
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFocusable(true);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.abc);
        image = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.x);
        mBackgroundImage =   a.getDrawable(R.styleable.y);
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackgroundImage);
    }

   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int width = image.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int height = image.getIntrinsicHeight();
        location = calculatePosition();
        image.setBounds((int) location, 0, (int) (location + width), height);
        image.draw(canvas);
   }
}
```

I want to add ripple on that drawable "image". I have search a lot but not found any solution. Then i signed up in stackoverflow. and now posting my first question. If anyone knows, please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dit you happen to find a solution for this?

Comment: I couldn't add ripple effect to drawable. but i draw a circle of ripple color on my drawable. It looks same as  ripple effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't add ripple effect to drawable. but i draw a circle of ripple color on my drawable. It looks same as ripple effect